# Jquery appended elements don't appear styled

Tags: jquery, html, css

So say I have:

```
$('#content').append('<div id="groups" style="width: 300px; background-color: #888;"><ul class="leftnav" style="list-style-type: none;">');
```

However it does not style correctly, the class nor the style itself works, it looks like I just did:

```
$('#content').append('<div id="groups"><ul>');
```

I would prefer to make class styling work instead of using style="" since I have :hover events etc etc

Comment: Don't see how that's possible given the information you've posted. Are you sure it's not got some control flow which is spitting out just the HTML without any styles?

Comment: be clear what exactly you need?

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you append with a class and have the styles set on the class?

Comment: Inspect the element with FireBug. My guess is you have styles elsewhere which are overriding those set on the element.

Comment: where is end tags inside append content

Comment: Yeah, that's the case with the ul, it has both a class and a style and neither seems to work

Comment: there's no class here, just an id ... better use class for styling ... id's are for making an element unique

Comment: I did use firebug and it shows that the styles exist, they just don't appear in the browser...

Comment: @kongaraju not needed as long as the browser can infer them correctly.

Comment: How are they supposed to appear? It's hard to see the background of an empty element or an element covered by its opaque children.

Comment: @JanDvorak: while it is true that closing tags are not needed, I think the lack of them might be instructive as for what the actual misunderstanding here is, as in my extended answer.

Answer (score 5):

The code you've written will append a DIV containing only an empty UL. This element will not have height, and therefore no background color will be shown. The style `list-style-type: none;` will not be visible either, as you have no list items.

If you are adding items to the list, they will have the style you've specified.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yyb2e/)

Note, however, that `append` will insert *actual DOM nodes*, not just pieces of HTML text. That means that `$('<div>')` will be an actual DIV, and not just an opening tag.

If you expect that your tags will be left open in the document, so that you could somehow just go on to add elements to `#content` [in this manner](http://jsfiddle.net/Sbaj7/), you'll see that the elements are added outside the `#groups` (since groups is immediately closed after the UL), and your styles won't be applied.

Comment: I know, I didn't include the whole code, it adds stuff later this is just the beginning.

Comment: @user1469988: Are you at a later point doing another append adding `li` items to `#content`, expecting them to be inside the UL because the UL wasn't closed? Because that's not how appending with strings works.

Answer (score 0):

Set the height of the div

```
height:100px;  // You will see the difference
               // as the UL is currently empty
```

You need to `set the height` of the div as it is static and the content inside is empty..

Comment: Closing tags are not neccessary and the height could take some explanation as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should place end tags.   height also the considerable point

```
 $('#content').append('<div id="groups" style="width: 300px; height:200px; background-color: #888;"><ul class="leftnav" style="list-style-type: none;"></ul></div>');
```

Comment: while they could be argued as a good style, closing tags are not neccessary.

Answer (score -2):

```
$('#content').append('<div id="groups"><ul class="leftnav" style="list-style-type: none;"/></div>');​
```

Code changed as above

http://jsfiddle.net/sameerast/U3qbB/1/

Comment: The snippet you're appending is not valid HTML.

Comment: First it was mistake, then u hv given me minus vote and said not valid.

Comment: So you fixed the mistake... still it says "locked in" and won't let me undownvote. Does the system think I downvoted the new revision?